# lxterminal blurry fonts

Tags: terminal

I have installed Raspbian Stretch on my RPi3. Whenever I open the lxterminal the text is quite unclear/blurry, it sometimes appears as the text is almost overlapping. I tried all the fonts given in configuration, but every single font looks messed up.

In contrast, the xterm shows extremely sharp text and blinking for the text (bash codes) work as well.

Is there any way I could make the lxterminal display sharp text as well? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you might have zoomed in or out by accident. Try using the key shortcut **ctrl + shift + 0** to reset your zoom setting.  Else try resetting the lxterminal.conf.  First if you want to backup your lxterminal settings use:

`cd ~/.config/lxterminal/ && cp lxterminal.conf lxterminal.conf.bak`

Then: 
`rm lxterminal.conf`

Now open a new lxterminal instance. It should have reverted to its default settings.  Lastly, you could also try using **sudo apt purge lxterminal** followed by **sudo apt install lxterminal** to remove and replace lxterminal with a fresh install.

Comment: `sudo apt --reinstall install lxterminal` should also do.

Comment: The default font "Monospace Regular" works great.  I changed to several other fonts.  Each one truncated characters.  Generally a HORRIBLE experience.  Resetting the entire config fixed it as this answer points out.  Or just know the default font works a lot better and choose that!